# CFNetwork error handling in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsurlconnection, cfnetwork

I have a block of objective-c code that responsible for handling HTTP errors by checking the `NSError` code error. The code sends the error message back to a delegate (unless it's a error code that the app ignores, such as cancelled requests)

```
failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, NSError *error, id responseObject) {

   NSString *errorMessage = [self getErrorMessage:responseObject withError:error];

   if (error.code!=kCFURLErrorCancelled &&
      error.code!=kCFURLErrorCannotFindHost &&
      error.code!=kCFURLErrorCannotConnectToHost &&
      error.code!=kCFURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost &&
      error.code!=kCFURLErrorDNSLookupFailed &&
      error.code!=kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet &&
      error.code!=kCFURLErrorTimedOut) {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didFailed:)]) {
      [self.delegate didFailed:errorMessage];
    }
  }

  if (completionBlock != nil) completionBlock(NO);
}];
```

I have several questions / issues related to this code block.

1. Is is sufficient to just check the error code? The framework I'm using might return a different type of errors and I'm not sure those error codes are unique.
2. How would I go and write the same code in Swift? I did find the error codes definitions under `CFNetworkErrors` enum. However, the `error.code` & the value from the `CFNetworkErrors` enum cannot be compared directly, as they have different types. Is it possible to cast `error.code` to a `CFNetworkErrors` and then compare the error codes?
3. Can I safely switch to use the `NSURL` errors such as `NSURLErrorCancelled`? Is there a 1-to-1 mapping between the CFNetworks errors and NSURL errors?

Comment: There are NSURLErrors matching all these CF errors; no need to use them at all. See NSURLError.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is probably not sufficient to check the error code.  You almost certainly need to check the HTTP status code as well, unless the delegate method you're calling already does that.  An NSError typically tells you about transport-level failures, whereas the status code tells you about server-side failures, such as a file not existing.
2. No idea.  That question is mostly unrelated to networking, so you should probably ask a separate question for it, and tag it as a Swift question.  :-)
3. Yes, you should be using the Foundation codes.  The values should always be identical, but there are likely to be more Foundation error codes than CF codes going forward, as not all of the Foundation-level functionality is exposed publicly at the CF layer.

Comment: You get _either_ an error code or a status code. Not both. You get an error code if you didn't get a connection to the server. You get a status code if you got a connection to the server and the server replied.

Comment: Although that is *usually* true, it is not always true, at least if you're using delegates—not sure about the block-based API.  You get a status code when the client receives a complete set of *headers*.  In the headers, the server sends a Content-Length header (or a chunked encoding header) that tells the networking stack how much data to expect.  If the connection fails while the server is retrieving that data, you should get both a successful status code and a transport error code like NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost or NSURLErrorTimedOut, depending on the underlying cause.